# UI control with grouping

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm looking in silverlight for a control that support grouping and the possibility to customize the group header with a template (like a grid with text and images)

I tried the DataGrid, but I can set only a String as the group header (or if I'm wrong how can I display a string and two images?)

Thank you
Francesco

BTW: I'm using MVVM and bindings.

EDIT: I'm looking primarily to something standard (microsoft) or free component. Or we (the company for which I work) already use ComponentOne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use the FlexGrid of ComponentOne.
In this way I used the grouping mode to group (together with the disclosure function), and the merging function to merge the first column of each group.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify free or not but if you are looking for off the shelf products [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com) offers a number of Silverlight controls. Their RadGrid allows for custom datatemplating as well as your other requirements of grouping and image usage.

Another good one that I have used on testing but never in production is jibGrid on Codeplex. You may want to check that one out as well  [jibgird on CodePlex](http://jibgrid.codeplex.com/) It does support grouping but I can't recall usage of images in the header.

If you are looking for using the default datagrid you can customize the header and column headers using datatemplates [See this msdn link for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.columnheaderstyle%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) As far as grouping, sorting and filtering this is not offered out of the box as with the aforementioned controls. To do this you will need to write a little code own your own. [This msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) provides some steps on how to accomplish this.

Hope this helps

Comment: Some default Microsoft control?